# how to get the id of sub-items of the list?

Tags: jquery, html

I've a list. I want to get the id's of the sub-items of each list. And if there are no sub-items, then the id of the main list., ie under location I want to gwt `region,country and state`, under device `gateway_unit, meter_unit` and since there are no sub-items under `global parameters` and `user`, hence want there ids.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked navigation" id="configuration_sidebar_content">
    <li>
        <a>Location</a>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked " id="location" style="padding-left:30px;">
              <li class="active" id="Region"><a href="#region">Region</a></li>
              <li id="country"><a href="#country">Country</a></li>
              <li id="state"><a href="#state">State</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="device">
        <a>Device</a>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="padding-left:30px;">
              <li id="gateway_unit"><a href="#gateway-unit">Gateway Unit</a></li>
              <li id="meter_unit"><a href="#meter-unit">Meter Unit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="user"><a href="#user">Software User</a></li>
    <li id="global_parameters"><a href="#global-parameters">Global Parameters</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is what I'm doing. Where I'm going wrong?

```
$(function(){
    $('#configuration_sidebar_content').on('click', 'li', function(){
        var selected_id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(selected_id)
  });
});
```

Comment: No it is working, http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/ucM2Y/

Comment: What's wrong with the result? Are you wondering why you get two alerts every time you click, and the second one says `undefined`?

Comment: Please see my edited description on the top. Thanks.

Comment: Your code does what your description says. Try Praveen's fiddle.

Comment: I dont want the second alert. Just only once. On the sub-item that I click. I dont want the parent id

Comment: Use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent getting the parent ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('#configuration_sidebar_content').on('click', 'li a', function(){
        var selected_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        alert(selected_id)
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JKeHL/

Comment: If this is what you wanted, you described it poorly. I click on Location, it displays "undefined", not Region, country, and state.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('#configuration_sidebar_content').on('click', 'li', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var children = $(this).find("li");
        var ids;
        if (children.length) {
            ids = $.makeArray(children.map(function () {
                return this.id;
            }));
        } else {
            ids = [this.id];
        }
        alert(ids.join(', '));
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ucM2Y/11/)

Comment: Seems like we are mistaken? Accepted answer and question contradicts i believe. :)